# List subset based on element values

Tags: python

I have a Python list where list elements need to be compared to create a subset list.

List item element 3 and 4 should be greater than 5 points to consider it as a unique item else the item can be treated as the same item.

```
inputList = [[0, 'F', 537, 187], [1, 'F', 606, 399], [0, 'F', 537, 187], \ 
    [1, 'F', 606, 400], [0, 'F', 606, 399], [0, 'F', 537, 186], \
    [0, 'F', 537, 186], [0, 'F', 605, 400]]
```

Expected output list

```
outList = [[0, 'F', 537, 187], [1, 'F', 606, 399]]
```

Following is the Python3 code, I am not sure where the error is, the expected output is not received.

```
outList = []
for item in inputList:
    if len(outList) == 0:
        outList.append(item)
        continue

    for item2 in inputList.copy():
        if abs(item[2] - item2[2]) > 5 and abs(item[3] - item2[3]) > 5:
            if item not in outList:
                outList.append(item)
```

Received output

```
[[0, 'F', 537, 187], [1, 'F', 606, 399], [1, 'F', 606, 400], \
[0, 'F', 606, 399], [0, 'F', 537, 186], [0, 'F', 605, 400]]
```

Let me know where I am doing a mistake.

Comment: What is the output or error you're getting?

Comment: Can you describe the logic of how you're trying to compare?

Comment: The logic is not well described...

Comment: modified the description to describe the logic.

Comment: Why shouldn't `[1, 'F', 606, 400]` be in the output?

Comment: Looks to me as if all items are meeting your criteria not just what you expect. You are comparing all items to each other. Is your intend to only compare to the first?

Comment: `[1, 'F', 606, 399]` should be in the output as it is unique compared to the item `[0, 'F', 537, 187]`

Comment: @SetV: So, the logic is to compared all items to the first item: is it that ?

Comment: @codrelphi That is not the requirement. Pick the unique items and add to a new list.

Comment: @SetV that doesn't make any sense, according to your logic the output list should contain 5 items (4 "unique" plus the first)

Comment: @NickMartin Unique is defined if the points are more than 5 points

Comment: You always arbitrarily choose whichever first input item you see. So you can replace the redundant code `if len(outList) == 0: outList.append(item); continue` with simply initializing `outList = inputList[0]`, then just iterate over `inputList[1:]`

Comment: @SetV this is the "delta" list compared to the first element:
`deltaList = [[0, 'F', 0, 0],[1, 'F', 69, 212],[0, 'F', 0, 0],[1, 'F', 69, 213],[0, 'F', 69, 212],[0, 'F', 0, 1],[0, 'F', 0, 1],[0, 'F', 68, 213]]`
there are 4 elements that meet your criteria...

Comment: It's much more user-friendly and makes for shorter code to refer to your columns as A,B,C,D instead of `item[0],[1],[2],[3]...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something as follows :

```
inputList = [[0, 'F', 537, 187], [1, 'F', 606, 399], [0, 'F', 537, 187],
    [1, 'F', 606, 400], [0, 'F', 606, 399], [0, 'F', 537, 186],
    [0, 'F', 537, 186], [0, 'F', 605, 400]] 

outList = []
for item in inputList:
    if len(outList) == 0:
        outList.append(item)
        continue
    #indicator flag for new element is initialized to true
    isnew=True
    for item2 in outList.copy():
        if abs(item[2] - item2[2]) <= 5 or abs(item[3] - item2[3]) <= 5:
                isnew=False
                break
     #if all elements have enough distant (5) from current element, flag maintains true and element is inserted
    if isnew and  item not in outList:
        outList.append(item)

print(outList)
```

output:

```
 [[0, 'F', 537, 187], [1, 'F', 606, 399]]
```

Comment: Understood my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `pandas` package for non-trivial manipulations of 2D data (dataframe), instead of what you're doing. The code will be cleaner and clearer.

```
import pandas as pd      

df = pd.DataFrame(inputList, columns=['A','B','C','D']) # name the columns instead of `item[2],[3]...`
df.sort_values(by=['A','B','C','D'], inplace=True)

>>> df
   A  B    C    D
5  0  F  537  186
6  0  F  537  186
0  0  F  537  187
2  0  F  537  187
7  0  F  605  400
4  0  F  606  399
1  1  F  606  399
3  1  F  606  400
```

Now you can apply whatever manipulations you want. In your case you will always (arbitrarily) choose the first input item you see, i.e. `inputList[0]` or `df.iloc[0]`; let's call that `row0`. You then also (iteratively) choose any items whose C and D values are both larger/smaller by > 5 than the C,D values of the first item. But it is possible to formulate this non-iteratively rather than your existing iterative method which is going to be O(N^2). For example:

```
row0 = df.iloc[0]

df[ df.apply(lambda r: abs(r.C - row0.C)>5 and abs(r.D - row0.D)>5,  axis=1) ]

   A  B    C    D
1  1  F  606  399
3  1  F  606  400
4  0  F  606  399
7  0  F  605  400
```

or:

```
>>> df.groupby('C').head(1)
   A  B    C    D
5  0  F  537  186
7  0  F  605  400
4  0  F  606  399
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in your comparison logic:

```
for item2 in inputList.copy():
    if abs(item[2] - item2[2]) > 5 and abs(item[3] - item2[3]) > 5:
        if item not in outList:
            outList.append(item)
```

If `item` differs from *any* element by 5 points, then you consider it a separate item.  You have to iterate through *all* of the items -- and fail to find a match -- before you add it to `outList`.

```
for item2 in inputList.copy():
    if abs(item[2] - item2[2]) <= 5 and abs(item[3] - item2[3]) <= 5:
        break
else:
    outList.append(item)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 'F', 537, 187]]
```

According to your description, the other element in your "expected output" is wrong: `606, 399` matches `605, 400`.  If the difference in the first element is supposed to differentiate these, then you must add that to your description and to your code.

```
    if item[0] == item2[0] and          \
       abs(item[2] - item2[2]) <= 5 and \
       abs(item[3] - item2[3]) <= 5:
```

Comment: `[1, 'F', 606, 399]` should be in the output as it is unique compared to the item `[0, 'F', 537, 187]`

Comment: By that criterion, your original output seems to be correct: each of the elements is unique compared to at least one other.